# jsonpickle datetime to readable json format

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, jsonpickle

Is it possible to convert datetime into a readable JSON format (which could be used from javascript)? Currently jsonpickle provides only a binary encoded value for datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I came up with the following solution:

```
class DatetimeHandler(jsonpickle.handlers.BaseHandler):
    def flatten(self, obj, data):
        return obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

jsonpickle.handlers.registry.register(datetime, DatetimeHandler)

encoded_datetime = jsonpickle.encode(datetime.now())
print(encoded_datetime)
decode_datetime = jsonpickle.decode(encoded_datetime)
print(decode_datetime)
```

Comment: the resulting decode_datetime is typed unicode, not the original datetime. The first answer is better suitable for marking as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

There are several gotchas here:

First, please don't traffic in timezone unaware datetime objects. You will feel pain, not today, maybe not tomorrow, but someday. You can learn from others' mistakes (mine), or you can learn the hard way. As far as I'm concerned the fact that Python allows you to make datetime objects without a timezone at all is a bug.

Second, you can't reliably roundtrip `strftime()` and `strptime()` for timezone-aware datetime objects. This was [fixed](https://bugs.python.org/issue22241) for UTC in Python 3.6, but still fails for other timezones.

Instead use `datetime.isoformat()` and `datetime.fromisoformat()`. These were added to the `datetime` class in Python 3.7 (and [backported](https://pypi.org/project/backports-datetime-fromisoformat/) to earlier versions).

Third, `jsonpickle` does not clearly document how to roll your own `DatetimeHandler`. So yeah, you just want something legible that you send to Javascript or whatever? The solutions above will be fine. You want something that's legible but you also want to pull it back into Python at some point? Um, trickier.

Here's a hint: when you are subclassing a library to extend its capability, look carefully at the superclass you are extending.

I would have written `DatetimeHandler` somewhat differently. But the following works, and contains all my hard won wisdom on the subject. Ouch.

```
import pytz
import jsonpickle
from datetime import datetime

class Blah(object):

    def __init__(self, blah):
        self.datetime = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
        self.blah = blah

    def to_json(self):
        return jsonpickle.encode(self)

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_str):
        return jsonpickle.decode(json_str)

class DatePickleISO8601(jsonpickle.handlers.DatetimeHandler):
    def flatten(self, obj, data):
        pickler = self.context
        if not pickler.unpicklable:
            return str(obj)
        cls, args = obj.__reduce__()
        flatten = pickler.flatten
        payload = obj.isoformat()
        args = [payload] + [flatten(i, reset=False) for i in args[1:]]
        data['__reduce__'] = (flatten(cls, reset=False), args)
        return data

    def restore(self, data):
        cls, args = data['__reduce__']
        unpickler = self.context
        restore = unpickler.restore
        cls = restore(cls, reset=False)
        value = datetime.fromisoformat(args[0])
        return value

jsonpickle.handlers.registry.register(datetime, DatePickleISO8601)
```

Comment: Absolutely! Please do.

Comment: This answer is superior to the accepted one because it is reversible. The whole point of `jsonpickle` is that, as its name suggests, it is an analogue of `pickle`, so reversibility is implied and important.

Comment: Extended question. I am receiving data from an API that `jsonpickle` renders as `"date": {"py/object": "datetime.date", "__reduce__": [{"py/type": "datetime.date"}, ["B+ULEA=="]]}`. The only suggestion on this page that works for me is `unpicklable=False`, but it causes the data returned to be massive — 100Mb or more. None of the others have any effect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

With current version of jsonpickle (obtained from pip as of today), it seems plain use of encode just works, if setting unplickable to false:

```
>>> import jsonpickle
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> jsonpickle.encode(datetime.now(), unpicklable=False)
'"2014-05-25 20:24:30.357299"'
```

However, your trick can be used to produce [ISO 8601 format](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15), which could be more adequate, accoding to ECMAScript v5 specs:

```
>>> class DatetimeHandler(jsonpickle.handlers.BaseHandler):
...     def flatten(self, obj, data):
...             return obj.isoformat()
...
>>> jsonpickle.handlers.registry.register(datetime, DatetimeHandler)
>>> jsonpickle.encode(datetime.now(), unpicklable=False)
'"2014-05-25T20:31:30.422826"'
```